# Finding stationary points numerically

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

I'm writing a program which needs to be able to find the stationary points of a function within a given interval, and evaluate whether these points are maxima, minima or points of inflection.

Using [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) I can find the derivative at a given point, but I'd prefer not to have to check every point on the function for a zero derivate, but I can't think of / find a better method. Once I have a stationary point, I should be able to use numerical differentiation techniques to find the second derivative (and thus whether it is a maxima, minima etc.)

How can I estimate the stationary points without checking every point on a line?

Comment: You can consider using methods like the Newton's method and the alike.

Comment: Additionally, you may use some additional structure, such as convexity.

Comment: Gradient descent (or affine methods) could be fine to find max/minimum points

Comment: @RSerrao I hadn't seen how I could use Newton's method, as I didn't know the differentiated function, but upon reading the Wikipedia page on Newton's method for optimisation I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can make use of methods like the **Newton's method** and other similar ones, to calculate fixed points of functions on intervals when the functions satisfy certain criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it set me on the right tracks. Unfortunately this is harder than I expected as methods like Newton's give a turning point, but I need all of them! I'm looking into seeds etc. now to try and solve that.

Comment: @acernine If your interval is not that big and you can afford not to have the most accurate answers, you can try splitting it into some subintervals (how many would depend on plenty of things) and then try to apply newton's method on every subinterval.

Comment: @acernine for a given subinterval, you would apply it until it converges or until the iterations create values outside the current subinterval. When the method's iterations start converging, you apply it until your solution is within the error you want, that is $|f(x) - x| < \epsilon $ for some $\epsilon $ representing the tolerated error.